# SWT system color displays RGB incorrectly

Tags: java, windows, colors, swt, eclipse-rap

I am running RAP(RemoteApplicationPlatform) on a Windows machine.
There is a default theme applied to most RAP widgets.

```
TableItem.setForeground(Display.getDefault().getSystemColor(SWT.COLOR_DARK_MAGENTA))
```

This code results in lime green font color when applied to a TableItem. For every system-based color code the expected output color is incorrect. I noticed that when applying the same code to a different widget (eg: Button) I get a different color that the TableItem.

Anyone know what is happening here? I have not modified my system color theme in any manner, and the change in colors across different widgets leads me to believe that the GC used in painting is having some problems replicating these colors - as if there were an overlay?

I have a general fear of having to manage resources since I have so many, and need to color match across OS, even if in the SWTResourceManager class and would very much prefer to stick to OS dependent colors.

I will try to find the generated html code for the tableitems. Unfortunately RAP, being generated html/js does not make this easy.